# Handling bad records during sqoop export

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

In the sqoop cookbook, it mentions how "it does not offer the ability to skip corrupted rows," I was wondering if this was still the case.

If so, does anyone have any recommendations on how expanding the export functionality to be able to skip the corrupted row and continue processing the export? My alternative thinking is to have the map tasks commit to the database more frequently (export.statements.per.transaction)

thanks!

Comment: Check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1856